# How to use data of a specific column from any row?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS 2010 C# ASP.NET 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2

On an aspx I read data from the database and present it as a grid view.
Both the gridview and the datasource are part of the aspx.

There is no problem with that.

Now, I wish to use the same datasorce, and present the data which resides in a specific column and one row (any row = the column has identical values on each row)

How do I do that?

I thought to use a repeater, and limit it's adavance, but I do not find a way to do that.

I wrote that:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Col").ToString() %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How do I stop the repeater after one iteration?

Because I found no way of limiting / stopping the repeater, I get a row of the same number as a result.

How do I get only the first, last or any other value, but only one value from this clumn?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hint, not an answer. Look into the asp:Repeater events. Specifically ItemDataBoundEvent. There are slso methods by which you can control the repeater once you intercept the ItemDataBoundEvent.
I hope it helps